# How to remove decimal from variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have created a code to work out pay of workers, and to - 1 of pay for charity if it is over 100, and every 10 over 100 -1. But I need to get rid of the decimal with new pay variable. At the end of the if function

```
Dim donation As Single
Dim newpay As Single
Dim hourlyRate As Decimal
Dim pay As Decimal
Dim hours As Single

Sub Main()


    Console.WriteLine("how many hours have you worked this week?")
    hours = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("what is your hourly pay?")
    hourlyRate = Console.ReadLine

    pay = hours * hourlyRate
    newpay = pay

    If pay > 100 Then
        pay = pay - 1
        newpay = newpay - 100
        donation = donation + 1

        newpay = newpay / 10

        Math.Floor(newpay)

        pay = pay - newpay
        donation = donation + newpay

    End If

    Console.WriteLine("you earned £" & pay & " and donated £" & donation & " to charity")
    Console.ReadLine()




End Sub
```

Comment: Show CURRENT and DESIRED results.

Comment: I need the decimal to be removed from newpay variable at the end of if statement so I can currently work out how much money is given to charity. SO if newpay was 3.6 I need it to say 3 or if 5.4 to say 5

Comment: Use the `ROUND` function (or whichever equivalent function is available in VBA).

Comment: I have variable to integer so it removes it but it rounds it. I need it so if newpay was 6.5 it would be 6 not 7.

Comment: If you GOOGLE a little, you may find something like FLOOR function.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Math.Floor` function to round **down**

SO if newpay was `3.6`

```
Math.Floor(newpay)
```

will return `3`

SO

Use the result of this function

```
donation = donation + Math.Floor(newpay)
```

OR

```
newpay = Math.Floor(newpay)
```

Comment: I have added the math.floor function but it doesn't work

Comment: @bob what happened? whats the result of adding `math.floor`? what was supposed to happen?

Comment: It doesn't round down, for example 4.5 is meant to go to 4 but it stays at 4.5

Comment: I forgot to set newpay = to math.floor(newpay) thanks for the help.